# JSP Blank page jsessionid

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm creating a Web App with Java EE and when I run a blank page appears with no errors I don't really understand.

Sometimes in the URL I have `jsessionid=`

No errors on server Log and no errors in the code.

I already tried to check the filter and web.xml but I have 0 errors that's frustrating everything was working and now it's all gone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, no code, no clear error message, no real description of your app framework. Who knows? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it's just a jsp a servlet and a filter no errors and i just have url/jsessionid=dfjoljlfdjdlrf65f5v95 and a blank page

Comment: Oh, well in that case the problem is in your JSP. Or the container. Or a framework. See what I mean? Because, clearly, the JSP is processing the action and rendering a default of some kind. But we have no way of knowing how to help you without context.